# Regarding Spring AOP Exception Logging

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-aop

I am trying to get the exact line where the exception occurred using Spring AOP.

**Code in AspectLogger.java** :

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.ing.trialbal.*.*.*(..))", throwing = "ex")
public void afterThrowingAdvice(JoinPoint jp, TrialBalException ex) {
    logger.info("Exception : After throwing " + jp.getSignature().getName()
            + "()");
    logger.info("********* " + ex.getMessage()
            + " Exception occured during " + jp.toShortString());
    System.out.println("********* " + ex.getMessage()
            + " Exception occured during " + jp.toShortString());

}
```

**Code in DAO class from where I am throwing exception to Service :**

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("(((((((((((((" + e.getStackTrace().toString());
    throw new TrialBalException("Error.TrialBalance.Exception : " + e);
} finally {
    try {
        pStmt.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**In Log I am getting :** 
Exception : After throwing getLongTBDetail()
Error.TrialBalance.Exception : java.lang.NullPointerException Exception occured during execution(LongTBDaoImpl.getLongTBDetail(..))

I don't know how to get the exact line number where the error occured. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the original exception as cause to `TrialBalException`, which will then contain the original stacktrace (with line numbers). Then print the exception in your aspect.

Comment: Can you please be little more elaborate?